# Android : TextView setText only works at the first time

Tags: android

Every time enter the main activity, The code below will be executed and works fine(that means `indexStatus.setText(msg.obj.toString());` alway shows the latest msg).

But if I press `back` button to switch out, and then switch in the same screen(The `reBuildIndex` will run again), the `Log.d(TAG, msg.obj.toString());` works fine, print out latest msg, but `indexStatus.setText` doesn't work, the latest msg does not display as I expected.

What's going on here ? Any suggestion ?

```
void rebuildIndex(boolean reCreate) {
    final TextView indexStatus = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.index_status);
    indexStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    indexStatus.setText(R.string.rebuild_index_progress_title);

    final Handler statusHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
      @Override
      public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.obj == null) {
          indexStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (msg.obj.equals("show")) { // TODO quick demo, shouldn't use literal text.
          indexStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
          Log.d(TAG, msg.obj.toString());
          if (indexStatus.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            indexStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          indexStatus.setText(msg.obj.toString());
          indexStatus.invalidate();
        }
        return false;
      }
    });

    Indexer.rebuildIndexIfNecessary(statusHandler, reCreate);
  }
```

UPDATE:

I've added a `indexStatus.invalidate();` after `setText` in the third condition, doesn't work either.

UPDATE:
Wrong msg at original post, I said press `home`, but actually its `back` to switch out. `home` button switch out/in works fine.

UPDATE:
Tried to place the handler as a global variable, but didn't work. Now I disabled `back` event.

Comment: This is interesting. May I know what do you see (the message) when its not functioning as expected?

Comment: Can you give a little more info on where the `rebuildIndex()` is getting called again? Is it from `onResume()`? what actually triggers the method and what triggers the the `handleMessage()` of the `Handler`?

Comment: `rebuildIndex` is called from `onStart` of the activity, and the message is a normal literal `String`

Comment: @LightYearsBehind there's nothing display at all, seems the view is not visiable  at all

Comment: Sounds to me like "else" case is not called, but you said `Log.d(...)` works.. I assume you didn't call `Log.d(...)` elsewhere?

Comment: @LightYearsBehind `Log.d` is definitely works correctly, I've tried to print `indexStatus.getVisibility()`, and it also works & correct. This wired thing almost drive me crazy

Comment: This puzzled me as well! Can you please post the entire `Activity` code if possible?

Comment: That still puzzled me. Would need your `Activity` code so we can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Debug it and check it. you got idea what actually happened there.

Answer (score 0):

If the TextView needs to be always set visible in this part of the code:

```
if (indexStatus.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
    indexStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

then remove the `if` part.